# Обрабатывается несколько рас запрос ajax

Tags: ajax

Есть динамически созданные классы:

```
<div class='menuline' data1=''></div>
<div class='menuline' data1=''></div>
<div class='menuline' data1=''></div>
```

и т.д.

Мне нужно при нажатии на каждый menuline обработать запрос:

```
    $(document).delegate( ".menuline", "click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'info.php',        
        method: 'get',           
        dataType: 'html',          
        data: { data1: $(this).attr('data1')},    
        success: function(data){ 
        $('#menuserios').empty();   
        $('#menuserios').append(data);
        }
    }); 

});
```

При первом клике на элемент "menuline" мне выдает результат.
При втором клике дважды результат, при третьем - четыре раза и т.д. в геометрической прогрессии.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как ни будь, при каждом клике обнулять функцию? Чтобы при каждом нажатии на "menuline" она срабатывала лишь по одному разу.

Comment: Код, где аякс запрос, как вызывается? И можете привести пример, как вы видите что результат выводится многократно? В коде у вас есть очищение, а потом заполнение.

Comment: код где аякс запрос вызывается при клике на <div class='menuline'></div> 
Видно по памяти в консоли (и страница подвисать начинает), и если убрать строку $('#menuserios').empty(); то при каждом клике выдает результат в геометрической прогрессии (первый клик 1 результат, второй -3 результата, третий клик - 7, четвертый -15 и т.д.)

Comment: Какая версия jquery?

Comment: 3.7.1 - версия jquery

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).off(myFunction).on( ".menuline", "click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    // тут ajax запрос
}
```